# Can't get service in command class. Symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, symfony-console

**I need to connect the services on the command line via autowire.**

I use symfony 3.4 and I do not understand how to correctly register the settings for this. I have the following setting in app/config/services.yml:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    CoreBundle:
        resource: '../../src/CoreBundle/*'
        # you can exclude directories or files
        # but if a service is unused, it's removed anyway
        exclude: '../../src/CoreBundle/{Entity,Repository}'
```

In a command, I am trying to override the constructor method in command. I am trying to get a service through the constructor

```
<?php

namespace CoreBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use CoreBundle\Service\ObjectTypeService;

class TestCommand extends Command
{
    private $objectSevice;

    public function __construct(ObjectTypeService $objectSevice) 
    {
        $this->objectSevice = $objectSevice;
        parrent::_construct();
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('core:test')
            ->setDescription('');
    }
    
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        //some code…
    }
}
```

And i get error:

> Command "core:test" is not defined.
>
> Did you mean one of these?
>
> > core:check

And this doesn't work with entity manager:

```
<?php

namespace CoreBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use CoreBundle\Service\ObjectTypeService;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class TestCommand extends Command
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;

        parent::__construct();
    }

    //some code…
}
```

This is the error I get when I specify the argument type for dependency injection. If we remove these arguments, it works.

```
<?php

namespace CoreBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use CoreBundle\Service\ObjectTypeService;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class TestCommand extends Command
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    //some code…
}
```

**I do not know how to properly connect autowire so that it works inside the command class**

Comment: Where is `core:testCommand` even coming from? It's not in your question. Please post your Command class, because when can't see how it's configured.

Comment: @StephanVierkant i create this command. Added the console command class to the question

Comment: Does app/console debug:container CoreBundle show any of your bundle's services?  BTW, probably a copy/paste typo but it looks like you have an extra } in your exclude statement.

Comment: @Cerad Yes. This service is listed. And yes, it's a copy/paste typo =)

Comment: So that is encouraging.  Now drill down a bit further with 'app/console debug:container TestCommand' and verify the console.command tag is set.

Comment: @Cerad the tag is missing. Even in "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager" there are no tags either

Comment: So the lack of a tag means that Symfony does not know you have a command service so it just tries to new your command class.  I don't have a 3.4 project handy.  Normally autoconfigure will automatically tag any command that extends the Command class.  I would expect that 3.4 does the same but maybe not.  You don't have a CoreBundle/DependencyInjection folder do you?  You could try manually defining the command service and explicitly tagging it.

Comment: According to the docs, a Command will be registered as a service. I don't know what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

[Symfony's documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/console/commands_as_services.html) says:

> If you’re using the default services.yml configuration, the command class will automatically be registered as a service

So there's no need to register the commands in your config.

If you want to use Dependency Injection, extend your command from `Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command` instead of `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand`:

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;

class WarehouseExportStockCommand extends Command
{
    private $objectSevice;

    public function __construct(ObjectTypeService $objectSevice) 
    {
        $this->objectSevice = $objectSevice;
        parrent::_construct();
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

And you might want to follow the convention of lower case command names: `core:test:command`. I'm not sure if camelCase command names can case problems, but following Symfony's convention is usually a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, but It didn't work for me. I corrected my question. It's about the constructor. If you remove the objectTypeService from the arguments, it works. But now I get the same error

Comment: Is `ObjectTypeService` correctly configured as a service? I'd expect an error message if it fails, not a 'not defined' error.

Comment: Yep. This service is used in controllers in several bundles. At the moment I cannot use dependency injection even for entityManager. I get the same error